# Silverlight out of browser application cannot start

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

If I enable the Out of Browser application setting, the application doesn't run, doesn't even debug. Visual Studio compiles the app, switches to Debug layout but ends immediately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a new Silverlight project and moved all the files to the new one. Now it works without problems. I have no explanation for this but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you done steps mentioned in these 2 links?

http://johnpapa.net/10-steps-to-debug-silverlight-out-of-browser-applications-without-attaching

http://indiandotnet.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/silverlight-out-of-browser-application-oob-apps-in-simple-steps/

Comment: I don't test the Silverlight app with a test page. And it was working but something broke it which I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this problem, I also just had this occur. I followed Elodie's suggestion and created a new project and doing folder comparisons. Eventually it came down to an InBrowserSettings xml file. It was fixed by manually editing the .csproj file to remove the reference to that file and then deleting it from the Properties folder.